# Issue with parsing @odata values using Swift

Tags: ios, odata, swift4, decodable

**My service response is following:**

```
{
"@odata.context" = "https://xxx-d.www.com/odata/$metadata#Members";
"@odata.count" = 1;
 value = ({
        email = "Suamasu@xxx.com";
        memberType = User;
        name = "Suse";
        title = "Manager";
   });
}
```

I am able to decode `value` which using Decodable swift type, however I need **"@odata.count"** value to be decoded from response.

```
struct Members: Decodable {
    let value: [Member]
}

struct Member: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    let email: String
    let memberType: String?
    let title: String?
}
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON response here?

Comment: @MohitKumar response is already posted. I have updated model information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to add coding keys to Members?

```
struct Members: Decodable {
    let context: String
    let count: Int
    let value: [Member]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case context = "@odata.context"
        case count = "@odata.count"
        case value 
    }
}
```

More info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types